# How to verify xml digital signature in c# without using SignedXml?

Tags: c#, cryptography, .net-core, xml-signature

How to verify xml signature (used in SOAP requests) without usage of SignedXml (which is not available in dotnet core)?

I am trying like this, but it gives me false all the time:

```
 public static void CheckSignature(XElement responseXml, MyResponseType response)
    {
        string originalDigestValue = Convert.ToBase64String(response.Signature.SignedInfo.Reference.FirstOrDefault().DigestValue);
        var originalSignatureValue = response.Signature.SignatureValue.Value;

        X509DataType certificateData = (X509DataType)response.Signature.KeyInfo.Items[0];
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2((byte[])certificateData.Items[0]);

        //for calculating digest value
        //responseXml.Descendants(nm + "Signature").SingleOrDefault().Remove();
        //var digestValue = Convert.ToBase64String(SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseXml.Document.ToString())));

        XNamespace nm = @"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#";
        var signedInfoNode = responseXml.Descendants(nm + "SignedInfo").SingleOrDefault();

        var signedInfo = signedInfoNode.ToString().Trim();

        byte[] signedInfoBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signedInfo);

        var hash = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(signedInfoBytes);

        RSA rsa = certificate.GetRSAPublicKey();

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Signed Info: \n" + signedInfo);
            Console.WriteLine("Verification: \n" + rsa.VerifyData(signedInfoBytes, originalSignatureValue, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1));
            Console.WriteLine("Verification hash: \n" + rsa.VerifyData(hash, originalSignatureValue, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1));
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
           //
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the https://github.com/tintoy/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Security.Cryptography.Xml

Comment: I did, but there are just too many types that are not yet available in dotnet core 1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[xmldsig](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/) is a very large, very complicated spec.  You can try to implement it if you like, the complicated bits are turning the XML document into bytes for doing signing and verification (the [canonicalization (or c14n) spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315) is separate, and large).

SignedXml should be available now with [.NET Core 2.0 Preview 1](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/preview#windowscmd), and upgrading is definitely your easiest bet.